# Freebase Suggest with Chosen Plugin multiple selection

Tags: php, jquery, freebase

I am trying to use the Freebase Suggest plugin along with Chosen to create a multi-tag system. Something similar to stackoverflow's tagging system but pulled from Freebase.

Any pointers or is there something out there done that performs this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Ajax version of Chosen](http://blog.meltingice.net/programming/bootstrapping-chosen-ajax-autocomplete/). You should be able to configure it to use the [Freebase Search API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Search#Via_the_API) to populate the autocomplete drop-down with viable tags. The Freebase Search API supports JSONP so just make sure that you set the dataType in Chosen to "jsonp".

Please let us know if you get this working. It sounds like a pretty cool use of Freebase data.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I got it working in a different way but I will look into making it as a plugin and GitHubbing it soon, possibly using Ajax Chosen (cleaner than my version) :-)